# DSum & Converting Query Codes to VBA

Tags: ms-access-2013, cumulative-sum

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntmYN.jpg)

Refer link above for picture.

Hi. I want to have a `Running_Total` to calculate the `Total_Good_Count` by their product. I have successfully created it using Query. However that is not exactly I want.

For example, for `RecordID` 3, the `Running_Total` will be 684. `RecordID` 4, the `Running_Total` will be 684 + 964 = 1,648. Is it possible?

These are the current codes in the Query:

```
Running_Total:DSum("[Total_Good_Count]","2_WIP","[Product] = '"&[Product]&"'")

Total_WIP:[Running_Total]-[WIP_Cleared]
```

Additionally, how can I change these codes to VBA? I actually tried DSum in Query because most solutions online provided are in Query. The VBA Codes will then be in a button of a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
Running_Total: DSum("[Total_Good_Count]","2_WIP","[Product]='" & [Product] & "' And [RecordID]<=" & [RecordID] & "")
```

and:

```
Total_WIP: DSum("[Total_Good_Count]","2_WIP","[Product]='" & [Product] & "' And [RecordID]<=" & [RecordID] & "")-WIP_Cleared
```

Comment: I tried. It's still the same result as the original code

Comment: It can't be the same.

Comment: ooo apologies i realised i missed something out. It is working now. Thanks a lot! :-) Anyway, do you have any idea how i can put this code in vba? I do not want to have two separate table for just a calculation

Comment: So far so good. You have a query, I understood. So in VBA you can just call: `DoCmd.OpenQuery "NameOfYourQuery"`

Comment: I just realised that the `DSum` didn't work for `Total_WIP`. If you refer to my above formula, `Total_WIP` depends on the `Running_Total`. For example, the Running Total for `RecordID` 3 is 684. Once I input `WIP_Cleared` to 600, `Total WIP`: 684 - 600 = 84. So, by right all the running total has to be reduced by 600 right? Is there a way?

Comment: Additionally I've tried to add the VBA code for the Query in my form button. This form button belongs to another different table. I really appreciate your help if you can assist me step by step with my issues. >.<

Comment: As for Total_WIP see edited answer (though you have not marked it as so). As for your button, I don't follow; a button doesn't "belong to a table" ... so?

Comment: Hmm... Okay what I am trying to say firstly for `Total_WIP` is that once I minus off 600, shouldn't the all the records have to be minus by 600 too? `RecordID` 3: 684 - 600 = 84, `RecordID` 4:  1648 - 600 = 1048. So on and so forth. The previous total is 684 + 964. Now it is not accurate even though `RecordID` 3 total has changed, all other records still remain the same as before.

Comment: Secondly, I will like to avoid using Query for DSum since I already have a table `2_WIP`.  The records for `2_WIP` comes from another table `1_Daily_Entry`. I used `Insert_Into` function to copy all the records over by a button in a form linked to `1_Daily_Entry`. Is there a way for me to put all these Queries into VBA? Additionally, `2_WIP` has a Search Form linked to it. I do not want to put the codes in a form field because I want to store these query in the table `2_WIP`.

Comment: Okay apologies. I have changed the picture. Maybe you'll get a clearer picture

Comment: My expression for Total_WIP seems correct given your revised example data. As for your form/queries considerations, this is really too broad for this forum. Have in mind please, that we don't have neither your application nor your data. A better place could be [Experts Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com)